# Have align image left, text center, image right on the same line

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to align two images one to the left and the other to the right of text. then have the text flow down the middle not underneath the images. I figured this should be fairly easy but cant get it to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/b9nc02cu/

```
<div style="width:100%">
<div style="float:left"><img style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg"></div>

<div style="float: left; top: 150px; left: 5px;"><span style="font-size: 30px;">Today is September 12, 2015. It's a saturday partly cloudy</span></div>

<div style="float: right;"><img style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaaJpe Something like this perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b9nc02cu/3) one.

```css
#container {
   width: 100%;
}

#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

#left {
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

#middle {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 150px;
}

#right {
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
    <div id="left">
        <img style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg">
    </div>
    
    <div id="middle">
        Today is September 12, 2015. It's a saturday partly cloudy
    </div>
    
    <div id="right">
        <img style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg">
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfect added width:100% to middle.

Answer (score 0):

img and span elements have an inline display.

Removing the parent divs for each of the 3 elements will give you the result you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should set the width of the middle column. If you're aiming at newer browsers you could set it to calc(100% - 300px);

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="float:left"><img style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg"></div>
    <<div style="float: left; top: 150px; width: calc(100% - 300px);"><span style="font-size: 30px;">Today is September 12, 2015. It's a saturday partly cloudy</span></div>
    <div style="float: right;"><img style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b9nc02cu/1/

Comment: when using calc, don't forget the space on either sides of the minus (-)

Comment: what about not fixed width?

Comment: Not quite sure, but I think you pretty much need to have fixed width if you want the behaviour he asked for. However, you can use percentages and stuff.